# How to show detail of Exception causes in log files

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, exception

I have a logfile from Tomcat which shows the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.package.MyClass
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1858)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
... 33 more
```

The upper part of the Stacktrace (removed everything before the cause because it doesn't show the information I need) only shows Spring-internal classes. However, this error comes because someone forgot to report a transitive dependency for the war file...

Is there a way to ***configure Tomcat*** to show the hidden stacktrace lines?

Note: `exception.getCause().printStacktrace()` is not what I am looking for, I want all stacktraces to be printed in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Don't really know how to configure it in Tomcat but, if the error is something that happens when initializing the Spring Servlet you can extend it and print the exception manually:

```
public class StartupErrorSafeDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {

    private Logger logger = ...

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        try {
            super.init(config);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(t));
            logger.error("{}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(t));
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Guava library which provides a method getStackTraceAsString](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html#getStackTraceAsString%28java.lang.Throwable%29):

> Returns a string containing the result of toString(), followed by the
>   full, recursive stack trace of throwable. Note that you probably
>   should not be parsing the resulting string; if you need programmatic
>   access to the stack frames, you can call Throwable.getStackTrace().

You can also consider looking at [Package java.util.logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) something like

```
Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
Exception e1 = new Exception();
Exception e2 = new Exception(e1);
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception", e2);
```

Comment: This would not help as I need to control that from the WebAppContainer, not from code... That's why I asked for a way to configure Tomcat... I'm trying to find out who forgot the dependency, so I can hardly ask them to print their exceptions... And, the exception is printed by Spring during Bean construction...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, use `org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils`:

```
ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(Throwable th)
```

gives you a String with the whole trace. Now you can print it the way you prefer

```
try{
    //something 
}catch(Exception exception){
    System.out.println(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exception));
    logger.error("{}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exception));
}
```

Comment: This would not help as I need to control that from the WebAppContainer, not from code... That's why I asked for a way to configure Tomcat... I'm trying to find out who forgot the dependency, so I can hardly ask them to print their exceptions... And, the exception is printed by Spring during Bean construction...