# Get more detailed Spring Bean Initialization Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, classnotfoundexception, spring-bean

I am getting some Exception like this when starting Tomcat:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mycompany/mypackage/SomeClass
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:176)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:122)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:870)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1263)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1948)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.mypackage.SomeClass
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1858)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
... 33 more
```

So, this means, some bean could not be initialized by Spring because it directly (or worse, indirectly) references the class com.mycompany.mypackage.SomeClass

I find this Stacktrace quite bad, as it tells the symptom, but not the root cause. I need to know what bean is not being initialized, so I can talk to the person responsible for that bean so he can decide wether "SomeClass" should be in the classpath or not.

Is there any trick to find out what bean is not being initialized?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show detail of Exception causes in log files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280074/how-to-show-detail-of-exception-causes-in-log-files)

Comment: @WornOutSoles, In fact it is not a duplicate. I would rather delete the other question as it is imprecise, I was asking the wrong question. Editing the other question to make it like this one would make the existing answers invalid, so I preferred to close-vote the bad question.

Comment: You could've modified the other question before creating this on. Anyway, it doesn't matter ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Set the logging level to `debug` on `org.springframework` and you will get a much more detailed log of where this exception is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I have never had any problem identifying a failing bean, they always show up in your **log4j** file . It shows the exact cause of the error, for instance:

```
o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet ERROR - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in file [...\HomeController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    ...
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NonExistent
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:240)
    at .......HomeController.<clinit>(HomeController.java:17)
```